# How to module programming in luabind( OOP, object-oriented programming)

Tags: c++, lua

Using "require", I want to link a lua file that represents a base class.

lua_class1.lua(base class)

```
   class 'lua_testclass'

    function lua_testclass:__init()
        self.name = name
    end

    function lua_testclass:f(Value)
        Value[1] = 10000
    end
```

"lua_test1.lua(derived class)"

```
   require "lua_class1"

    class 'lua_testclass_wrapper' (lua_testclass)

    function lua_testclass_wrapper:__init()
        lua_testclass.__init(self, name)
    end

    function lua_testclass_wrapper:f(Value)
        lua_testclass.f(self, Value)
    end

    a = lua_testclass('example')
    b = lua_testclass_wrapper('example')
```

cpp file references a global object "a" and "a" object calls "f" member function. But, The program was abnormally terminated.

```
luaL_dofile(pLS, "lua_test1.lua");
object objParam = newtable(pLS);
object obja = globals(pLS)["a"];
objParam[1] = 10;
call_member<void>(obja, "f", objParam);
int nParam = object_cast<int>(objParam[1]);
```

By the way, The following is OK..

```
class 'lua_testclass'

function lua_testclass:__init()
    self.name = name
end

function lua_testclass:f(Value)
    Value[1] = 10000
end


class 'lua_testclass_wrapper' (lua_testclass)

function lua_testclass_wrapper:__init()
    lua_testclass.__init(self, name)
end

function lua_testclass_wrapper:f(Value)
    lua_testclass.f(self, Value)
end


a = lua_testclass('example')
b = lua_testclass_wrapper('example')
```

I tried this way, but It was failed.

```
Mod = require "lua_class1"

class 'lua_testclass_wrapper' (Mod.lua_testclass)

    function lua_testclass_wrapper:__init()
        Mod.lua_testclass.__init(self, name)
    end

    function lua_testclass_wrapper:f(Value)
        Mod.lua_testclass.f(self, Value)
    end
```

Is there a good way?

Thanks.

Comment: "enter image description here" is not a question.

Comment: Please add your tried code and error log

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2486888)

Comment: Danny, welcome on StackOverflow. I'm sorry to tell but this is a terrible first question. Please, take the time to take the [tour], then read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I tested this case in many ways. I included base class lua file("lua_class1.lua"). 
Then, It worked very well.
I wondered that this source is how to work.

```
luaL_dofile(pLS, "lua_class1.lua"); //include base class file
luaL_dofile(pLS, "lua_test1.lua"); 
object objParam = newtable(pLS);
object obja = globals(pLS)["a"];
objParam[1] = 10;
call_member<void>(obja, "f", objParam);
int nParam = object_cast<int>(objParam[1]);
```